# PHP - How would I inject a file into a download? Or do it this way?

Tags: php, jar, download

i'm trying to make it so that when a users downloads a file, it first generates a random key(I got that part done) but now the random key needs to be put into the download and then downloaded. I have came up with two options. Which one is best and how do I do it?

1) Inject the key.
    I thought that I can just make it so before the file(A jar) is downloaded I inject into the jar itself
2) Zip it
    I also thought that I can generate a random key, make a file, add the file and the jar into a zip and start downloading the zip.

All help is appreciated.

Don't understand why this was down voted by I fixed the capitalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write the file for download as a byte stream you can add the bytes of your key into the stream. If you want it to be part of the file, you would need to know what the proper byte offset is to add your bytes.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean? I have nevr heard of byte streams in PHP

Comment: I'm not an expert on how PHP deals with bytes, but basically every file is just a collection of bytes, if you don't care about encoding. Take a look at the pack and unpack functions. If there's no byte streams, you can load the file as a byte array, overwrite or add your bytes then repack into a file.

Comment: Okay, so with my zip way, what functions would i use?

Comment: If you want to create a new file with the key and add it to a zip, you would do that with system commands on your server, then send the zip'ed file. Or maybe you have the zip extension installed and can use these commands: http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php

Comment: Thank you for your help! I just could _not_ find any help. Will be sure to make this as correct. Again thanks :)